# Button shows which one is picked (Constant Color) - PowerBI

Tags: function, powerbi, dax

The layout of my page has 6 tables and three buttons. Clicking on any of the buttons will change which table is shown on the main page, I did this through bookmarking. Now my question is, is there a way to have the button I click change to a certain color. To show / indicate which button is currently pressed? Or is there a dax function that could help with this as well. I know you can do the two-button thing one which is default and the other which is press button. But that is only for pressing and it reverts back to the same color after pressing. Or have the button bookmark to an identical page with a switch color icon. But that just leads to a lot of redundant work. I want it to where it stays the color until another button is pressed then that button changes color as its now the one picked.

There might be a simple solution but through google might have overlooked the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Overlay a button with a lighter/darker color and include this in the bookmark that is activated by clicking the original button, so it will look like it's gone a dark/lighter shade.
- Link closing the bookmark to the new overlay version of the button since it will be obscured by the overlay.

Comment: Thank you, was a simple answer regarding the buttons and got it by adding a button and bookmarking the changes

Comment: mikejr, mark the answer if it solved your case